# Connect stereo L+R pair to 2x stereo IKEA FREKVENS speakers

Tags: stereo, mono, setup

After waiting for a year or two I’m superhappy with the Frekvens lights and audio units. For sure it’s no pro audio but hey, nice for playing around...

I’m now puzzeling for the right setup and connection.

I would like to make the audio unit a wired stereo pair to amplify my OP1. I have read a couple of threats but still not sure how to connect it the right way.

So I have 2 frekvens 10x20 and 1 sub. I can connect a stereo male minijack to the OP1 to a splitter that makes it double mono (L+R) to both of the units. The volume has to be set spereately per speaker but I guess that will be ok. Is this the right way to connect the speakers? Or is it the wrong way to connect with 2x mono cable in stereo input if I want stereo sound?

When I connect the sub to the L speaker I guess I only get the sub sound form L. So can I use a double mono male jack from L and R to feed the sub via a stereo male minijack to get the sub repond to both L&R?

Anyone who can help me solve this puzzle?

Best regards. 
Bas [image][image]